How to send a telegram message without blocking main thread
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio

TOKEN = "blah"
CHAT_ID = 1

async def send_message_async():
    message = "This is a test update from the bot!"
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message)
    print("Message sent successfully!")


async def main():

    print("Before sending message...")

    await send_message_async()

    print("After sending message...") # I don't want this to be blocked until the message is sent


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

I'm trying to send message without blocking whole thread, but I'm struggling to avoid it. Is there any way?
I am hoping to find a simpler API to above problem. Something like below
def send_message():
    # Sends message to user asynchonously without blocking the main thread
    pass

def main():
    # Main function
    send_message()

But it seems like, to call one async function, every other function should be converted into async function.

if you don't want to block it then run bot in separate thread or process. OR don't use awaitbecause it waits for end of function but useasyncio create_task()`.

If you don't want to wait then don't use await but create_task()
task = asyncio.create_task(send_message_async())

You can use await task at the end of program to check if you may exit program
or you have to wait for end of this task.
# wait for end of task
await task
# or 
result = await task

You may also use if task.done(): to check it without blocking code.
if task.done():
    result = await task
else:
    # ...


from telegram import Bot
import asyncio

TOKEN = "blah"
CHAT_ID = 1

async def send_message_async():
    print('starting send_message_async()')
    message = "This is a test update from the bot!"
    #bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    #await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("Message sent successfully!")

async def main():

    print("Before sending message...")

    task = asyncio.create_task(send_message_async())
    #await send_message_async()

    print("After sending message...")

    await asyncio.sleep(6)

    print("End...")

    # wait for end of task (to makes sure it finished)
    await task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


Example with more print() to show that functions run at the same time.
from telegram import Bot
import asyncio

TOKEN = "blah"
CHAT_ID = 1

async def send_message_async():
    print('starting send_message_async()')
    message = "This is a test update from the bot!"
    #bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    #await bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message)
    
    for i in range(10):
        print('sending', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        
    print("Message sent successfully!")

    return "It's done!"

async def main():

    print("main: Before sending message...")

    task = asyncio.create_task(send_message_async())
    #await send_message_async()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
    #print(dir(task)) # 
    
    print("main: After sending message...")

    for i in range(3):
        print('main', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    print("main: End")

    while not task.done():
        print('main: waiting for end of task')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    # wait for end of task
    #await task 
    result = await task  # if function use `return` to send result
    print('main: result:', result)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Result:
main: Before sending message...
starting send_message_async()
sending 0
main: After sending message...
main 0
sending 1
main 1
sending 2
main 2
sending 3
main: End
main: waiting for end of task
sending 4
sending 5
main: waiting for end of task
sending 6
sending 7
main: waiting for end of task
sending 8
sending 9
main: waiting for end of task
Message sent successfully!
main: result: It's done!


Thanks! This is working as I intended and I'll be using this. but is there any way to avoid defining main as async function? Like .then in javascript instead of await.

in JavaScript everything is async and .then runs it also as async code - so it may need another .then to work with results from previous .then - fetch().then().then(). And it has built-in async loop so it doesn't need asyncio.run() but Python doesn't has built-in async loop so it needs asyncio.run() and run() needs async function main(). But in JavaScript you can also use await to run code like normal function.

in Python create_task() works like normal function in JavaScript. As I remember it has function .add_done_callback() which can be execute at the end of function but I didn't test it.

Difference between async await in python vs JavaScript - Stack Overflow

I found module promisio which works like JavaScript - it has then()

Got it, I'm still trying to wrap these over my head. but for now, I'll just accept I have to define my parent function (main) has to be async. haha
